# Substituting curried function's args for Units

Tags: function, scala, currying, unit-type

(**invalid**)

What is the best way to partially substitute arguments in a curried function for Units:

```
trait Expr[A] { def apply : A }

type Reaction[A] = A => Unit
type TypedReactor[A] = Expr[A] => Reaction[A] // aka Expr[A] => A => Unit
type FlatReactor = () => () => Unit

def flatten[A](e: Expr[A], r: TypedReactor[A]): FlatReactor = ???
```

So a curried `Function1` needs to be transformed left-to-right to a curried `Function0`.

The following works, but looks pretty awkward:

```
def flatten[A](e: Expr[A], r: TypedReactor[A]): FlatReactor = () => { 
  val unc = r(e); val eval = e.apply; () => unc(eval)
}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, there was a mistake. The flatten function actually looks like this:

```
def flatten[A](e: Expr[A], r: Reaction[A]): FlatReactor = () => { 
  val eval = e.apply; () => r(eval)
}
```

So I don't think it can be any more simplified than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just substituting your various vals directly into a single expression gives:

```
def flatten[A](e: Expr[A], r: TypedReactor[A]): FlatReactor =
  () => () => r(e)(e.apply)
```

Which looks fine to me?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it more clear: `e.apply` must be called in the first application; this is to 'cache' it and make it consistent across multiple reactors, and in the second application they are free to act back on any dataflow variables. There was also a mistake in the question formulation :-(